# Why does shutdown write in the client cause the connection to be closed?

Tags: linux, sockets, rust

**NOTE:** No error appears if the shutdown in client is deleted

```rust
// server.rs
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use std::net::Shutdown;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:4000").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let mut stream = stream.unwrap();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
            let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
            let len = reader.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();

            // no sleep no error, just simulating a time-consuming operation
            thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));

            stream.write_all(&buffer[0..len]).unwrap();
            stream.shutdown(Shutdown::Write).unwrap();
        });
    }
}
```

```rust
// client.rs
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let mut clients = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..1000 {
        clients.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut client = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:4000").unwrap();
            client.write_all("hello".as_bytes()).unwrap();
            
            // no error if remove the following line
            client.shutdown(std::net::Shutdown::Write).unwrap();

            let mut buffer = Vec::new();
            client.read_to_end(&mut buffer).unwrap();
            println!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap());
        }));
    }

    for client in clients.into_iter() {
        client.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

As I understand, shutdown the write operation will append FIN after sending the previous data, and then the peer (server) can still continue to write data. But among these 1000 clients, some error appeared:

```
// server
<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 107, kind: NotConnected, message: "Transport endpoint is not connected" }', src/bin/server.rs:22:46
```

```
// client
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 104, kind: ConnectionReset, message: "Connection reset by peer" }', src/bin/client.rs:15:45
```

It seems that the connection is closed after the shutdown in client.

Update1:
I used Wireshark and this is one of the wrong connections:

```
No.     Time        Source      Destination Protocol    Length  Info
1101    13.738139   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         56      10628 → 4000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
1104    13.738157   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      4000 → 10628 [RST, ACK] Seq=409345761 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
1234    14.251615   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         56      [TCP Retransmission] [TCP Port numbers reused] 10628 → 4000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
1250    14.251690   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         56      [TCP Port numbers reused] 4000 → 10628 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
1266    14.251726   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      10628 → 4000 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2161152 Len=0
1376    14.251949   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         49      10628 → 4000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2161152 Len=5
1387    14.251970   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      4000 → 10628 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=6 Win=2161152 Len=0
1402    14.251996   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      10628 → 4000 [FIN, ACK] Seq=6 Ack=1 Win=2161152 Len=0
1412    14.252013   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      4000 → 10628 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=7 Win=2161152 Len=0
2092    15.261312   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         49      4000 → 10628 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=7 Win=2161152 Len=5
2101    15.261384   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      10628 → 4000 [RST, ACK] Seq=7 Ack=6 Win=0 Len=0
```

Update2:
One of correct connections:

```
No.     Time        Source      Destination Protocol    Length  Info
162     13.731960   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         56      10927 → 4000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
166     13.731997   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         56      4000 → 10927 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
169     13.732013   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      10927 → 4000 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2161152 Len=0
176     13.732035   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         49      10927 → 4000 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2161152 Len=5
181     13.732046   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      4000 → 10927 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=6 Win=2161152 Len=0
187     13.732059   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      10927 → 4000 [FIN, ACK] Seq=6 Ack=1 Win=2161152 Len=0
191     13.732074   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      4000 → 10927 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=7 Win=2161152 Len=0
1495    14.746260   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         49      4000 → 10927 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=7 Win=2161152 Len=5
1502    14.746369   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      10927 → 4000 [ACK] Seq=7 Ack=6 Win=2161152 Len=0
1505    14.746423   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      4000 → 10927 [FIN, ACK] Seq=6 Ack=7 Win=2161152 Len=0
1512    14.746529   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP         44      10927 → 4000 [ACK] Seq=7 Ack=7 Win=2161152 Len=0
```

Comment: *"But among these 1000 clients, some error appeared"* - does this mean the error only happened once and the other 999 connections had no issue? Is this reproducible?

Comment: It is reproducible. For me, it happens to anywhere between 5% and 50% of the clients.
I suspect that it has to do with the capacity for unaccepted connections (the `listen(3, 128)` output from strace), but don't have a good explanation yet.

Comment: @kmdreko Yes, it is reproducible.

Comment: 'no sleep no error'........what is the sleep for?

Comment: @MartinJames Just simulating a time-consuming operation

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect it has to do with the backlog, the number of connections accepted by the OS TCP stack, but not yet handled by your application.
`std` doesn't allow you to control this number and defaults it to 128.

To control the number, I've re-implemented your server in tokio (well, it's actually just the main example on the tokio README), and set the backlog to 3000.

```
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpSocket};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:4000".parse().unwrap();
    let socket = TcpSocket::new_v4()?;
    socket.bind(addr)?;
    let listener: TcpListener = socket.listen(3000)?;

    loop {
        let (mut socket, _) = listener.accept().await?;
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut buf = [0; 1024];
            loop {
                let n = match socket.read(&mut buf).await {
                    Ok(n) if n == 0 => return,
                    Ok(n) => n,
                    Err(e) => {
                        eprintln!("failed to read from socket; err = {:?}", e);
                        return;
                    }
                };
                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                if let Err(e) = socket.write_all(&buf[0..n]).await {
                    eprintln!("failed to write to socket; err = {:?}", e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This makes the problem disappear. Reducing it to `socket.listen(128)` makes it reappear. (Disclaimer: I do not suggest that 3000 is a sane number for the backlog.)

I said I strongly suspect that this is the cause because I can't fully explain how the sleep causes the problem. It may be that the many sleeping threads slow down the scheduler, and thus the speed at which your server can accept connections. But that is speculation.

(Side note: My default ulimit for open files was fairly low. I had to increase it with `ulimit -nS 10000` to not get in the way when testing this.)

Comment: But with the same environment, no error appears if the shutdown in client is deleted. This is my main question.

Comment: Ah, I missed that comment. Sorry, no idea for that.